# Micro-managing memory usage for C process

Tags: c, unix

I wanted to implement memory management functions using C. The situation is like.. Total size of physical memory is `256mb`.

How can I allocate `128mb` to one process `64mb` to other process.

I want to implement best fit algorithm using `freelist` & needs to do compaction.
Can anybody help me in this regard, or suggest any book for studying the same?

Comment: This might help, but you should do some conceptual study about approach to manage memory i.e. a scheme / data structure to keep track of what is free, what is allocated and how to find new chunks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159564/implementing-malloc-in-c

Comment: What type of RAM banks do you have ? Depending on the size, you can easily dispatch the process thanks to the linker script.

Comment: What kind of context do you want to do it in?

Comment: Note: If you want to do it for two _processes_, it implies you are doing it in _kernel_, but thanks to virtual memory (or do you have an embedded system without MMU?) you don't need continuous memory there.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the maximum amount of memory a process can use (Resident Set) with

```
ulimit -m 131072
```

for example to limit all forked processes from your shell to 128mb of maximum resident set.

Or in C via

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
int setrlimit(int resource, const struct rlimit *rlim);
```

e.g.

```
struct rlimit rlim;
getrlimit(RLIMIT_RSS, &rlim);
rlim.rlim_cur = (128 << 20) / sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) // 128 MiB
setrlimit(RLIMIT_RSS, &rlim);
```