# What is meant by the most restrictive type in C?

Tags: c, architecture, malloc, long-integer, memory-alignment

The book *The C Programming Language* talks about "the most restrictive type" in section 8.7, *Example — A Storage Allocator*:

> Although machines vary, for each machine there is a most restrictive
>   type: if the most restrictive type can be stored at a particular
>   address, all other types may be also. On some machines, the most
>   restrictive type is a `double`; on others, `int` or `long` suffices.

In their code, the `union` `header` is aligned using the type `long`.

What is meant by the most restrictive type? Is it perhaps the largest type (e.g., `double`), or is there another approach?

Comment: define an union of all types and see the size of the union to find out the most restrictive type

Comment: @BsD - that gives you the largest type. It may or may not be the most restrictive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CPUs often require that (or work more efficiently if) certain types of data are stored at addresses that are a multiple of some (power-of-two) value. This value is called the *alignment* of the data. For example, a CPU might require that four-byte integers are stored at addresses that are a multiple of four (that they have *four-byte alignment*, or are *aligned on four bytes*).

By *the most restrictive type*, they mean the type that has the most restrictive requirements in this area. So if e.g. `long double` requires eight-byte alignment on some machine, and no other type requires greater alignment than that, then the most restrictive type on that machine would be `long double`.

It makes sense for `malloc(3)` to return addresses that satisfy the alignment requirements of the most restrictive type, since that means the returned memory can be used to store any type. `malloc()` doesn't know how the memory will be used, so it can't adapt.

It's not necessarily the case that larger data types require greater alignment, though alignment requirements tend to increase with increasing size.

(Some types of data might require even greater alignment than `malloc()` provides. For example, many x86 [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) instructions use data vectors that are aligned on 16 bytes, while e.g. the `malloc()` in glibc only guarantees eight-byte alignment. `posix_memalign(3)` can be used to dynamically allocate memory with even greater alignment requirements on POSIX (*nix) systems.)

Answer (score 5):

The most restrictive type is defined by `max_align_t`, which is defined in `stddef.h`. According to the standard:

> A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or
>   equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all
>   contexts, which is equal to
>   `_Alignof (max_align_t)`.

So `max_align_t` has an alignment that is *at least* as large as that of every scalar type, and in most implementations its alignment will be equal to the largest scalar type - but this equality is *not* required by the standard.

The standard further requires (emphasis mine):

> The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to
>   the `aligned_alloc`, `calloc`, `malloc`, and `realloc` functions is
>   unspecified. **The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
>   suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
>   of object with a fundamental alignment requirement** and then used to
>   access such an object or an array of such objects in the space
>   allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

So any pointer returned by allocation functions is aligned *at least* as strictly as the alignment of `max_align_t`.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but maybe they wanted a higher-level overview of the concept of alignment requirements of types. Digging into `max_align_t` and passages from the standard might be a bit overkill before you get that part.

Comment: @Ulfalizer Fair enough, but that doesn't really justify a downvote.. The question wasn't entirely clear to me, and my answer was specifically geared towards the "What means the most restrictive type, maybe the largest type size (f.e. double) or there is a another approach" part of the question.

Comment: Yeah, I personally only downvote spam and answers with obviously horrible advice. I agree that it's crappy to not give a reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the quote means the most restrictive alignment of types. For example char is the least restructive type if to follow this logic. An object of type char does not impose a constraint on its alignment while for example type int has alignment requirement of usually 4 byte bounds. Thus int is a more restrictive type than char.