# What is the alignment of data on the stack?

Tags: c, architecture, malloc, memory-alignment

I read K&R C(2nd) 185p and one part was hard to understand.

> Although machines vary, for each machine there is a most restrictive type: if the most restrictive type can be stored at a particular address, all other types may be also. On some machines, the most restrictive type is a **double**; on others, **int** or **long** suffices.

I think 
most modern computers are byte-addressable(by wiki). The smallest data type **char** is enough to fit in any stack area. So all data types are adequate to arbitrary stack position. But why does such restriction exist? 
 
 In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916061/what-is-meant-by-the-most-restrictive-type-in-c) similar question,

> CPUs often require that (or work more efficiently if) certain types of data are stored at addresses that are a multiple of some (power-of-two) value.

This explains about my question. But I couldn't understand it. Does that mean certain addresses of a power of two(2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 1024, 2048, ...) in the stack require certain types?
If so, why? Or if I'm wrong, What does it refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons to align data:

- Hardware requirement. Some machine can only access data in memory if it's properly aligned. Sure, you could perform multiple reads and use some bit arithmetic to emulate reading from any address, but that would be devastating to performance.
- Performance. Even if a machine can access any data at any address, it might perform better if the data is suitable aligned.

Of course, this could vary by machine, but "suitably aligned" usually means the address of an N bit datum is evenly divisible by N/8.

So, on a machine where alignment matters, a 32-bit `int` would be placed at a memory address divisible by 4, a 64-bit pointer would be placed at a memory address divisible by 8, etc.

You can see this in structures.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
   uint32_t u32;
   void*    p;
   uint8_t  u8;
} Struct;

int main(void) {
   Struct s;
   printf("%p\n", (void*)&s.u32);
   printf("%p\n", (void*)&s.p);
   printf("%p\n", (void*)&s.u8);
   printf("%p\n", (void*)(&s+1));
   printf("0x%zx\n", sizeof(s));
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && ./a
0x7ffef5f775d0
0x7ffef5f775d8
0x7ffef5f775e0
0x7ffef5f775e8
0x18
```

This means we have this:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
+-------+-------+---------------+-+-------------+ 
| u32   |XXXXXXX| p             |*|XXXXXXXXXXXXX|   * = u8 
+-------+-------+---------------+-+-------------+   X = unused
```

Note the wasted space between `u32` and `p`. This is so `p` is properly aligned.

Also note the wasted space after `u8`. This is so the structure itself is properly aligned when you have an array of them. Without this final padding, the `u32` and `p` of the second element of the array wouldn't be properly aligned.

Finally, note that using

```c
typedef struct {
   uint32_t u32;
   uint8_t  u8;
   void*    p;
} Struct;
```

would have resulted in a smaller structure.

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f 
+-------+-+-----+---------------+
| u32   |*|XXXXX| p             |   * = u8 
+-------+-+-----+---------------+   X = unused
```

Comment: Wow, I understood it! Your answer even explains a padding of structure. I got one question about your first example(larger structure). With that structure, alignment is (4(u32), 4(x), 8(p), 1(u8), 7(x)) and the same alignment continues if we have an array of it. But this is also possible to set 3 bytes padding at the end instead of 7. Then two patterns will be repeated as ((4, 4(padding), 8, 1, 3(padding)), (4, 8, 1, 3(padding))). Is it also possible to certain system?

Comment: Re "*But this is also possible to set 3 bytes padding at the end instead of 7*", No. A structure's size needs to be divisible by its largest alignment restriction. This is 8 in our case. and `0x14` isn't evenly divisible by 8. Let's show why that is using an example. Let's say the array starts at address 0x1000.  `a[0].u32` would be at 0x1000 (ok), `a[0].p` would be at 0x1008 (ok), `a[1].u32` would be at 0x1014 (ok), but `a[1].p` would be at 0x101C (not ok). The extra four bytes of padding push `a[1].u32` to 0x1018 (ok), and `a[1].p` to 0x1020 (ok)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ikegami/397927c88f711c4bc5cd042a34338487