# argc giving erroneous value in C program

Tags: c, shell, osx-mavericks, argc

I want to enter some command line arguments at run time. Like

```
./program abc def ghi
```

`argc` would be 4 in this case. No problem in this. But if I do

```
./program abc def *
```

or even

```
./program * abc def
```

the variable `argc` gives me a value far larger than 4.

On printing the entire `argv` array (leaving aside the 0th argument; `./program`) as strings, I am given a list where the first two elements are `abc` and `def` and the others are all file names of the files contained in the working directory.

I am trying to learn C from K&R. I was trying to make an RPN calculator where we can give expressions like `./program 2 4 *`.

What is the reason for this? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Look up "globbing" BTW: try `/bin/echo abc def *` , instead of your program.

Comment: The * is probably interpreted by your shell and replaced with all the files in your current directory.

Comment: thanks. but whats the workaround?

Comment: This is something your OS does before passing the parameters. You should probably tag this question with the relevant OS (I'm guessing Linux). As a side note, avoid K&R, it is completely outdated, filled with errors and bad programming practice.

Comment: @Lundin, not the OS, but the shell. You could run `bash` under cygwin and get the same behavior.

Comment: @Lundin: Can you please explain why K&R is outdated, filled with errors and bad programming practice? I opened a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258883/why-is-the-kr-book-outdated-filled-with-errors-and-bad-programming-practice and it seems that at least some people disagree with your claim.

Comment: @juhist [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159564/explain-this-implementation-of-malloc-from-the-kr-book) for example. To briefly sum up why the book is bad: 1) it is filled with bad programming practice and bad program design, 2) it is filled with bugs, errors and typos, see the book's errata which is several pages, 3) It has been outdated with the release of Amendment 1 to C90, then outdated completely with the release of C99, then outdated again with the release of C11, 4) there are countless religious fanatics encouraging the use of the book for no rational reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shells have a feature called [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), where they expand certain patterns, such as `*` to the matching files. If in the current directory you have the following:

```
file1 file2 somethingelse dir1
```

then calling:

```
any_program *
```

will be equivalent to:

```
any_program file1 file2 somethingelse dir1
```

Or if you do:

```
any_program fi*
```

it will be equivalent to:

```
any_program file1 file2
```

This is a feature of the shell. Your C program is well-behaved.

---

Since shells are different, let's assume you are using `bash`. To prevent `bash` from performing expansions, you should quote the argument. For example:

```
any_program "fi*"
```

will actually pass `fi*` to your program, without expanding it to `file1 file2`.

Comment: Yes you are right i am running bash and I tried this expression. : ./program abc def "*" and it gives argc equal to 4 alright!

Comment: @tectonicfury, globbing is a very useful feature. You just need to learn it so you can both use it effectively and not get into problems like you have.

Comment: i used linux at some point where i used to do commands like 'rm *.txt' or 'ls *.txt' so i am familiar with this behaviour but i didn't think that it would act this way even if I'm running a c program..

Comment: @tectonicfury, `rm` and `ls` are also just c programs ;) Anyway, so bottom line of what I'm saying is that `*` is expanded by the shell, and the application (regardless of the language) has no idea the parameters came from an expanded `*`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this info now its clear to me. perfect. theres a lot i need to learn lol.

Answer (score 3):

The commandline interpretter processes the `*` character as a wildcard before passing the arguments to your program, just the same as it does if you type `DIR *`.

The simple solution is to devise a meaningful parameter that does not get interpretted.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash, start the shell with the `-f` switch to turn off expansion of things like `*`

`bash -f`

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent * from expanding into file names by putting it into single quotes, i.e.

```
./program 2 4 '*'
```

This way your program will receive 3 input arguments with values "2", "4" and "*" in terms of C strings.